# How can I check if the response is a valid JSON in cocoa

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

Is there a way to check if the response from a web service call is valid JSON?

I am using ASIHTTP by the way for all communication.

Comment: is chris your friend :)... Here you go ;) & a vote up for you both

Comment: haha, sorry. Reflexive comment! You know how it can be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Attempt to parse the response—if you are successful, it's valid JSON. For example, if you were using [json-framework](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/):

```
SBJsonParser *parser = [[[SBJsonParser alloc] init] autorelease];
id object = [parser objectWithString:[request responseString]];

if (object != nil) {
  // Success!
}
```

Comment: FYI, if you're using the <a href="http://stig.github.com/json-framework/">library</a> referenced in this answer, that parser will spit out trace errors which can be handy if at least a part of your app concerns validating json.

Comment: Why would you use an external library when there's everything you need natively? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html